# Custom function to save a form using React Admin

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-admin

In my `react-admin` app, I have a list of items accompanied by two buttons: Create using email and create. The "create" button is pre-existing and uses the funcionalitties by the data provider. However, when I opt for "create with email", a different form appears. For this form, I wish to execute a custom function rather the default one provided by the data provider. How can achieve this?

I searched in the documentation and stackoverflow, but couldn;t find anything relevant...

Comment: u might want to show the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s not entirely clear what actions you want to take when saving, but here’s a similar example:
https://marmelab.com/react-admin/SaveButton.html#onclick

```
const MyToolbar = () => {
    const { getValues } = useFormContext();
    const redirect = useRedirect();

    const handleClick = e => {
        e.preventDefault(); // necessary to prevent default SaveButton submit logic
        const { id, ...data } = getValues();
        
// Your steps to save form values...
        
        redirect('list');
    };

    return (
        <Toolbar>
            <SaveButton />        
            <SaveButton type="button" onClick={handleClick} />
        </Toolbar>
    );
};

export const MyCreate = () => (
    <Create>
        <SimpleForm toolbar={<MyToolbar/>}>
          ...
        </SimpleForm>
    </Create>
);
```

Comment: that's exactly what I needed. thanks a lot!